# BackboneJS: this.$el undefined on other key value function (Backbone.View)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a code like this in JavaScript:

```
var addModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName:"div",
      el:$("#addemployee"),
      showbutton:$("#addemployee_button"),
      showbutton_click:function(e) {
          this.$el.modal("show"); // this.$el is undefined and not working
      },
      initialize:function() {
        this.showbutton.on("click", this.showbutton_click);
        this.$el.modal("show"); // this.$el is defined and working
      }
  });
myaddModalView = new addModalView();
```

Why is `this.$el` defined and working on initialize but not on other key index (`showbutton_click`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem all i need is to bind the backbone object on initialize.

```
var addModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName:"div",
      el:$("#addemployee"),
      showbutton:$("#addemployee_button"),
      showbutton_click:function(e) {
          this.$el.modal("show"); // this.$el is now defined and working
      },
      initialize:function() {
        this.showbutton.on("click", this.showbutton_click);
        _.bindAll(this, "showbutton_click"); // bind it first on showbutton_click
        this.$el.modal("show"); // this.$el is defined and working
      }
  });
myaddModalView = new addModalView();
```

This bind code is the solution and should be added on `initialize`: `_.bindAll(this, "showbutton_click");` so you can call the backbone object inside your custom function variables using the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The proper implementation should be like this using the `events` hash.

```js
var addModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#addemployee"), // should be avoided if possible
  events: {
    'click #addemployee_button': 'showbutton_click'
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.$el.modal("show");
  },
  showbutton_click: function(e) {
    this.$el.modal("show");
  },
});

myaddModalView = new addModalView();
```

If for some reason `#addemployee_button` is not inside `"#addemployee"`, then the event binding should happen in whichever view actually contains it.